# GDB Python: Parsing field name for structure array

Tags: python, gdb, gdb-python

Can anyone please explain how can i parse array of structure for getting fields of structure.

Using script mentioned in this 
[gdb python : Can anyone explain me how to use this script written in this post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483431/gdb-python-can-anyone-explain-me-how-to-use-this-script-written-in-this-post)

Trying to parse below structure:

```
typedef struct Q 
{
    int a;
    int b;
}Q;

typedef struct T 
{
    int x,
    int y;
    Q q;
}T;

struct S 
{
    T t[10];
    char b;
};
```

Comment: You probably want to replace "int x," by "int x;" in struct T definition.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "fields of structure"? Do you want a the value of a specific field for each of the `T` structures in `t[10]` contained in `S`?